# Google Drive API: find a file by name using wildcards?

Tags: google-drive-api

When using the Google Drive API v3, can one search for a file by its name using wildcards or regular expressions? [The docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) don't mention anything.

I am trying to match a set of files whose names have the format

```
backup_YYYY-MM-DD-XXXX_NameOfWebsite_xxxxxxxxxx.zip
```

And am wondering what's the best way to construct a pattern that might match it. Of course, I could follow the docs and just do something like:

```
q="name contains 'backup' and name contains 'NameOfWebsite'"
```

But if I need to match a different pattern, or something with more than 2 distinctive strings in its filename (*"backup_"* and *"NameOfWebsite"*), you can quickly see what a pain would be to construct a query in that way:

```
q="name contains 'string1' and name contains 'string2' and name contains...
```

Comment: Can't you just pass in your string variables into your query string? Doing `q="name contains 'backup' and name contains 'NameOfWebsite'"` is the same as doing `q="name = '*backup*NameOfWebsite*'"` if `*` was a wildcard.

Comment: You can't use wildcards in `q` search terms. You have to string `name contains` queries.

Comment: Also from the documentation: `The contains operator only performs prefix matching for a name. For example, the name "HelloWorld" would match for name contains 'Hello' but not name contains 'World'.` so you can't use `name contains 'NameOfWebsite'` for the middle of the file name either if there is no space before it. Read more about contains [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref#fields)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can't use a wildcard in the middle of a file name when making a `Drive.list` request with a q parameter.*

#### More Information:

The `name` field only takes three operators - `=`, `!=` and `contains`:

- The `=` operator is regular equivalence and with this you can not use a wildcard.
- `name = 'backup*'` will return no results.
- The `!=` operator is not equivalence, not relevant here but does the opposite of `=`
- The `contains` operator. You can use wildcards with this, but with restrictions:
- `name contains 'backup*'` will return all files with filenames ***starting with*** the string `backup`.
- `name contains '*NameOfWebsite'` will return all files with filenames that ***have a word starting with the string `NameOfWebsite`***. The file name `backup0194364-NameOfWebsite.zip` will ***not*** be returned, because there is no <kbd>space</kbd> before the string.

Therefore, the only way for this to work is if you do it the way you have already started to realise; string chaining:

```
name contains 'backup' and name contains 'NameOfWebsite' and name contains ...
```

#### References:

- [Files: list | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for files | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)