# Search file by name with hypens and contains operator

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the latest version (2.6.0) of the Google Api Php Client (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases?page=3) to interact with Google Drive and search for some files based on their names. The files I have are named in the following way: `Task-$task_id-Esercizi Ritmici.XXX`, were `$task_id` is an integer and `XXX` is the extension (e.g. mp3), below some examples:

- Task-1-Esercizi Ritmici.mp3
- Task-2-Esercizi Ritmici.mp3
- Task-3-Esercizi Ritmici.mp3
- ...
- Task-36-Esercizi Ritmici.mp3

Suppose I now want to search for the file "Task-3-Esercizi Ritmici.mp3". If I pass to the `q` query string (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files) the query `name contains 'Task-3-Esercizi Ritmici'`, then it matches all of the above files! This is very weird to me and, even after reading about how `contains` does prefix matching on the `name` property (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms), it still does not make any sense. Please note that this only happens with Task 3! For instance, if I search for `name contains 'Task-1-Esercizi Ritmici'`, then only the expected file "Task-1-Esercizi Ritmici.mp3" is returned... I'm pretty sure that this happens because of the ".mp3" extension, which causes a "3" to be present in every filename. It also seems like the hyphens are causing some issues with the `contains` operator, but unfortunately I haven't found much on the web and on the documentation.

Can you help me to understand what is actually happening here? How can I rewrite my query to only look for "Task-3-Esercizi Ritmici.mp3" without using the "=" operator (I don't want to specify the extension, because it might not always be ".mp3")? I would prefer not to change file names... but if there is no other solution how could I rename them to have some working queries?

P.s. (1) Just to make it weirder, if I search for `name contains 'Task-3-E'`, then only the correct file "Task-3-Esercizi Ritmici.mp3" is returned, same goes for `name contains 'Task-3-Ese'`. However, if I search for `name contains 'Task-3-Esercizi'`, then again all the above files are returned... This looks like magic to me and I can't wrap my head around it.

P.s. (2) I don't think it is an issue with the Php client library, since I get the same results by using the API test tool found at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms from your doc, seems that contains compare one string with the other without respecting the order.
That's why the prefix with 3 matches all (you are right about mp3 extension).
I would try to use 'Task-$task_id-Esercizi*'

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I don't fully see how what you said about "respecting the order" applies in my case. I tried your query (`name contains 'Task-3-Esercizi*'`) and it doesn't work, all files are returned.

Comment: I've finally found the old answer where I read it that using * should match the logic startingWith, which is your case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083163/google-drive-api-find-a-file-by-name-using-wildcards

Comment: I read that question too, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you also tried the exact match mentioned here? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files#php

9th line in the table says to use '"Task-$task_id-Esercizi Ritmici"' in your case

Comment: Yes I tried, but it does not work, all files are returned. However, if I use the query `fullText contains '"Task-3-Esercizi Ritmici"'` only the right audio is returned... but this is not really what I wanted to do, since I only care about the name of the files and not about their content.